# Combine similar CSV rows in python efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I want to combine similar rows in a very large csv files (nearly 1GB each!) into one. I'm interested in doing something like this:

**Before**

```
First Name | Last Name | Phone Number | Email

John       | Doe       | 1234         | john@doe.com
Jane       | Doe       | 4321         | jane@doe.com
John       | Doe       | 6789         | john@gmail.com
Jane       | Doe       | 9876         | jane@gmail.com
```

**After**

```
First Name | Last Name | Phone Number | Email

John       | Doe       | 1234, 6789   | john@doe.com, john@gmail.com
Jane       | Doe       | 4321, 9876   | jane@doe.com, jane@gmail.com
```

That is, to combine rows using the First and Last names, and the phone and email to add them up to a "list".

Thanks

Comment: If you've got a question tagged big data, you probably shouldn't be using itertools.

Comment: What should I be using?

Comment: Any big data or data crunching tool... numpy... pandas... spark... hadoop... etc.

Comment: @TripleNipple 1 GB is certainly a large file, but I would remove the `bigdata` tag for your question because 1 GB files can be processed on a single machine for your use case.

Comment: Removed :) Any ideas of what tags should I add instead ? :P

Comment: Yeah, if you can accomplish it on your laptop, then it isn't really `bigdata`, that's more for things that require *clusters* etc. Heck, nowadays, even *terabytes* are being called "medium data", and "big data" referring to petabytes and above!

Comment: Does a pandas solution work for you?

Comment: Well, can you actually hold the entire thing in memory, as a list-of-lists? Because then you could sort it, then `itertools.groupby`. Or else, maybe consider `pandas`

Comment: Any solution works for me! even pandas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read in your CSV file, you'll need `pd.read_csv`:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delimiter='|', sep='\s+')
```

You'll call `df.groupby` on `First Name` and `Last Name` and then `dfGroupBy.agg` to join:

```
print(df)

    First Name    Last Name  Phone Number            Email
0  John          Doe                 1234     john@doe.com
1  Jane          Doe                 4321     jane@doe.com
2  John          Doe                 6789   john@gmail.com
3  Jane          Doe                 9876   jane@gmail.com


out = df.astype(str).groupby(['First Name', 'Last Name']).agg(', '.join)
print(out)

                        Phone Number                           Email
First Name  Last Name                                               
Jane         Doe          4321, 9876   jane@doe.com,  jane@gmail.com
John         Doe          1234, 6789   john@doe.com,  john@gmail.com
```

If you want to reset the index, you can do so, using `df.reset_index`:

```
out = out.reset_index()
print(out)

    First Name    Last Name Phone Number                           Email
0  Jane          Doe          4321, 9876   jane@doe.com,  jane@gmail.com
1  John          Doe          1234, 6789   john@doe.com,  john@gmail.com
```

Saving to a csv is simple, you'll use [`out.to_csv('file.csv')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

---

**Appendix: Dropping Duplicates**

```
out = df.astype(str).groupby(['First Name', 'Last Name'])\
                .agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x.drop_duplicates().values))
```

Comment: Great job keeping the answer limited, easy to read and simple (+1)

Comment: Thanks! It worked ! 
Do you have any ideas of how can I embed in the same code a way to remove duplicates within the "Phone" or "Email" Column using the same code? like instead of having in the "Phone" column values like "1234,1234,1234,6789" I would have "1234,6789" ?

Thanks !

Comment: @TripleNipple The solution is using `drop_duplicates`. Check my edit.

Comment: df.insert(0,"Name",[" ".join(i) for i in zip(df["First Name"],df["Last Name"])]) to create new column with one Name.

Answer (score 0):

For a csv file that looks like this (with a bit a formatting to remove uncessary spaces) :

```
First Name|Last Name|Phone Number|Email
John|Doe|1234|john@doe.com
Jane|Doe|4321|jane@doe.com
John|Doe|6789|john@gmail.com
Jane|Doe|9876|jane@gmail.com
```

You can use pandas as follows, to combine similar columns (based on first and last name) :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/tmp/test.csv", sep="|")
df_combined = df.groupby(["First Name", "Last Name"], as_index=False).agg({"Phone Number":lambda x: ', '.join(str(i) for i in list(x)), "Email": lambda x: ', '.join(str(i) for i in list(x))})
df_combined.to_csv("/tmp/combined_data.csv", sep="|", index=False)
```

The output file looks like this:

```
First Name|Last Name|Phone Number|Email
Jane|Doe|4321, 9876|jane@doe.com, jane@gmail.com
John|Doe|1234, 6789|john@doe.com, john@gmail.com
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts!